# How to make a proper http request?

Tags: flutter, http, dart

I can't seem to make a proper http request with my code. Whenever I run the following code,

```
var url = Uri.https('datamall2.mytransport.sg', '/ltaodataservice/BusArrivalv2?BusStopCode=', {'BusStopCode': busStopCode});
  final response = await http.get(
    url,
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'AccountKey': accountKey,
    },
  );
```

I get the following error

```
I/flutter (24816): SocketException: OS Error: Connection refused, errno = 111, address = datamall2.mytransport.sg
```

This is the http request I'm trying to make

```
http://datamall2.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice/BusArrivalv2?BusStopCode=busStopCode (busStopCode is a 5 digit number)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrong protocol is being used.

You've requested httpS.
The server is only responding to http.

You could try something simpler:

```
String url = 'http://datamall2.mytransport.sg/ltaodataservice/BusArrivalv2?$busStopCode';
  final response = await http.get(
    url,
    headers: <String, String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'AccountKey': accountKey,
    },
  );
```

Comment: The latest http package requires a Uri instead of string though. I used to do it like this until I updated the pub spec version.

Comment: Ah, in that case: `Uri uri = Uri.parse('http://myrandom-url.com/with-stuff');` might be an easier way to create a URI object.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your url variable to:

```
var url = Uri.http('datamall2.mytransport.sg', '/ltaodataservice/BusArrivalv2', {'BusStopCode': busStopCode});
```

Comment: I get the error : Bad state: Insecure HTTP is not allowed by platform.

Comment: Oh never mind, apparently I need to add the following permissions:                  Android

Open the AndroidManifest.xml file in the android/app/src/main folder. Then set usesCleartextTraffic to true.

<application
    ...
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...   >

iOS

Open the Info.plist file in the ios/Runner folder. Then add the following key.

<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>